# Nested Groovy generics: unexpected token on inner generic type

Tags: java, generics, groovy, guava, hystrix

**Please note:** Even though this question specifically addresses [Netflix' Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix) library, this is definitely a pure Groovy/JVM generics question at heart. Any battle-weary Java/Groovy veteran should be able to answer this, regardless of their knowledge/experience with Hystrix.

---

I want to build an abstract base [`HystrixCommand`](https://netflix.github.io/Hystrix/javadoc/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.html) to return Guava [`Optionals`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) as their generic `RESULT` type:

```
import com.google.common.base.Optional
import com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand

abstract class BaseHystrixCommand<Optional<RESULT>> extends HystrixCommand {
    // My code here...
}
```

However this code produces the following compiler error:

> Groovy:unexpected token: < @ line 23, column 42.

Line 23 column 42 is the inner opening angle bracket for **`RESULT`**:

```
...BaseHystrixCommand<Optional<RESULT...
                              ^ right here
```

Using Java 8, Groovy 2.4.3, Hystrix 1.4.18 and Guava 18.0 here. Any ideas what is causing this compiler error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use intermediate types in your type parameters, you just declare the type parameters directly and then use a parameterized `Optional` as a method parameter or return type:

```
abstract class BaseHystrixCommand<T> extends HystrixCommand {
    Optional<T> someMethod();
}
```

You can also create a second, bound type parameter based on the first (though the example here is stupid, you wouldn't extend `Optional`), but you would need to specify its concrete type at instanciation:

```
abstract class BaseHystrixCommand<T, U extends Optional<T>> extends HystrixCommand {
    U someMethod();
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

[`HystrixCommand`](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/master/hystrix-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.java#L42) is actually a parameterized class, and you want to make its parameterized methods (such as `run()`) return an `Optional`. Just parameterize the `HystrixCommand` correctly in the subclass:

```
abstract class BaseHystrixCommand<T> extends HystrixCommand<Optional<T>> {
    // ...
}
```

Of course, all methods returning the parameterized type will now return an `Optional`, it stays consistent with the original declaration.

Side note: you really want to use single letters for parameterized types, to avoid the confusion with constants and follow the style conventions.

Comment: Thanks @Frank Pavageau (+1) - the problem is that by extending `HystrixCommand` I must override several methods, such as [`HystrixCommand#run`](https://netflix.github.io/Hystrix/javadoc/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.html#run()). I want my `run()` override to return an `Optional<RESULT>`, **not** just a `RESULT`. Any ideas here? It sounds like my only course of action is to perhaps subclass `Optional` with a dummy wrapper and then use `BaseHystrixCommand<OPTIONAL extends Optional<RESULT>>`?

Comment: For instance, something like `class OptionalWrapper<RESULT> extends Optional<RESULT> { }`?

Comment: I've edited my answer to address your additional question.